# CLR-Error: 80004005

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

when i try to start MusicBee, a Music Player based on .NET it says

> #### MusicBee.exe - Fatal Error.
>
> CLR-Error: 80004005.
>
> The program will be terminated.

(Translation from German)

Since I'm running Windows 10 RTM [Version 10.0.10240], I can't manage to re-install or repair the .NET Framework(s) because they are already integrated in Windows 10.

The error I get also didn't go away when I used System Restore to jump to a point when it still worked. Except MusicBee, two more programs called `ReStartMe` and `KeePass` stopped working, probably also because of a .Net error. (No error-message)

The next thing I want to try, is to repair the system using the original install medium but in my case I really want to avoid that. Does someone have an idea or a solution to this? I changed nothing prior to the error, not even a restart and I really need MusicBee to work on my system.

Answer (score -1):

I can understand how annoying this situation must be for you.

I suggest targeting lower versions of .Net as suggested here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx (unless you are using specific features in the newer frameworks/languages). That will fix any breaks that you may have in your targeted framework (unless the lower versions are broken as well).

Good luck. Post your result here if this suggestion works.

Comment: That's for a programmer creating their own app